# Has anyone tried putting Ubuntu on the new macbook pro retina?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, apple, macbook-pro

Has anyone tried putting Ubuntu on the new macbook pro retina? If so, were there driver issues? I really want to do this seeing that I am starting my computer science curriculum very soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in Virtualbox 4.2.1 on the Macbook Pro Retina. For the most part it works fairly well after installing guest additions.

It freezes up at times for a minute or so then catches up with itself. (Sometimes I get a black screen for 30 seconds or so until I see Ubuntu again.)

The only other issue might be the fact that since OS X is scaling the resolution, everything in Ubuntu looks slightly blurry. It's not too problematic for general tasks, however it can definitely be an issue if you are a designer who wants pixel perfect accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **Yes, it has been tried.**

There are a couple of people who have 12.10 up and running, though with a few hinges (flaky wifi, broken brightness control, no graphic switching). More information, including guides, screenshots, pitfalls:

http://cberner.com/2012/10/19/installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-macbook-pro-retina/#comments

http://www.warp1337.com/content/install-ubuntu-1210-quantal-quetzal-macbook-pro-101-retina-solved